# How to convert hts voice to Flite for android voice

Tags: android, flite, hts

Our company some time ago has developed a TTS voice for HTS engine. Now we were exploring to see if there's any way to use it with any TTS engine on Android. But so far there was no success.

I found that Festival can use HTS voices and Flite can also. But Flite for Android uses a seemingly different file format (.flitevox extension), which I found no clues on what is it and how to convert hts voices to it. Our voice is composed of some files with `.pdf`, `.inf` and `.win` files.

So my question is, is there any way to convert HTS voices to this flitevox format? Or in case of negative answer, is there any other TTS engine for Android that can support directly or indirectly HTS voices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, as the project owner said [here](https://github.com/happyalu/Flite-TTS-Engine-for-Android/issues/37), unlike HTS-patched Flite for PC, which can use HTS voices, Flite for android does not support them. And since the formats are very different, they are not inter-convertible. The only way now to use the HTS voices on Android, is to port the HTS-patched Flite on android.